# How to split 2 strings using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string into two strings using regular expression

For example

```
String original1 = "Calpol Plus 100MG";
```

The above string should split into

`String string1 = "Calpol Plus";` and `String string2 = "100MG";`

I tried using the `.split(" ")` method on string but it works only if the original string is  `"Calpol 100MG"`

As I am new to regex I searched a few regular expressions and made a regex as `"[^0-9MG]"`
but it still doesn't work on a string like `"Syrup 10ML"`

I want to use a general regex which would work on both the types of string.

Comment: Please clarify the criteria for splitting: when exactly should it occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your input according to one or more  space characters which was just before to the `<number>MG` string or `<number>ML` string.

```
string.split("\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])");  // Use this regex "\\s+(?=\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?M[LG])" if the there is a possibility of floating point numbers.
```

**Example:**

```
String original1 = "Calpol Plus 100MG";
String strs[] = original1.split("\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])");
for (int i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(strs[i]);
}
```

To assign the results to a variable.

```
String original1 = "Calpol Plus 100MG";
String strs[] = original1.split("\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])");
String string1 = strs[0];
String string2 = strs[1];
System.out.println(string1);
System.out.println(string2);
```

Output:

```
Calpol Plus
100MG
```

Code 2:

```
String original1 = "Syrup 10ML";
String strs[] = original1.split("\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])");
String string1 = strs[0];
String string2 = strs[1];
System.out.println(string1);
System.out.println(string2);
```

Output:

```
Syrup
10ML
```

**Explanation:**

- `\s+` Matches one or more space characters.
- `(?=\\d+M[LG])` Positive lookahead asserts that match must be followed by one or more digits `\d+` and further followed by `MG` or `ML`

**[ReGex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vG0iC9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String original1 = "Calpol Plus 100MG";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z ]+|[0-9]*.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(original1);
while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I present two solutions:

- You can create a pattern that matches the whole String and use groups to extract the desired information
- You can use look-ahead-assertions to ensure you split in front of a digit

Which solution works best for you depends on the variety of inputs you have. If you use groups you will always find the last amount-part. If you use split you may be able to extract more complex amount-groups like "2 tea-spoons" (with the first solution you would need to extend the `[A-Za-z]` class to include `-` e.g.by using `[-A-Za-z]` instead) or "2.5L" (with the first solution you would need to extend the `[0-9]` class to include `.` e.g.by using `[0-9.]` instead) more easily.

Source:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/27329519/1266906
 */
public class RecipeSplitter {

    /**
     * {@code ^} the Pattern has to be applied from the start of the String on
     * {@code (.*)} match any characters into Group 1
     * {@code \\s+} followed by at least one whitespace
     * {@code ([0-9]+\s*[A-Za-z]+)} followed by Group 2 which is made up by at least one digit, optional whitespace and
     *                              at least one character
     * {@code $} the Pattern has to be applied so that at the End of the Pattern the End of the String is reached
     */
    public static final Pattern INGREDIENT_PATTERN                   = Pattern.compile("^(.*)\\s+([0-9]+\\s*[A-Za-z]+)$");
    /**
     * {@code \\s+} at least one whitespace
     * {@code (?=[0-9])} next is a digit (?= will ensure it is there but doesn't include it into the match so we don't
     *                   remove it
     */
    public static final Pattern WHITESPACE_FOLLOWED_BY_DIGIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s+(?=[0-9])");

    public static void matchWholeString(String input) {
        Matcher matcher = INGREDIENT_PATTERN.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(
                    "\"" + input + "\" was split into \"" + matcher.group(1) + "\" and \"" + matcher.group(2) + "\"");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\"" + input + "\" was not of the expected format");
        }
    }

    public static void splitBeforeNumber(String input) {
        String[] strings = WHITESPACE_FOLLOWED_BY_DIGIT_PATTERN.split(input);
        System.out.println("\"" + input + "\" was split into " + Arrays.toString(strings));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        matchWholeString("Calpol Plus 100MG");
        // "Calpol Plus 100MG" was split into "Calpol Plus" and "100MG"
        matchWholeString("Syrup 10ML");
        // "Syrup 10ML" was split into "Syrup" and "10ML"
        splitBeforeNumber("Calpol Plus 100MG");
        // "Calpol Plus 100MG" was split into [Calpol Plus, 100MG]
        splitBeforeNumber("Syrup 10ML");
        // "Syrup 10ML" was split into [Syrup, 10ML]
    }
}
```